# How to renew the id token using auth0 in SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, auth0, auth0-connection

I'm using Auth0 for login and logout in my iOS app. after the user logs in I get an id token which I use to make the further api calls in my app. we need to keep updating the token with auth0 as mentioned in their [doc](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-swift/auth0-swift-save-and-renew-tokens#credentials-manager)
My function is as follows

```
struct UpdateToken {
let credentialsManager: CredentialsManager

init() {
    self.credentialsManager = CredentialsManager(authentication: Auth0.authentication())
}


func updateToken() {
    
    guard credentialsManager.canRenew() else {
        // Present login screen
        print("not renewing")
        return
    }
    Auth0
        .webAuth()
        .scope("openid profile offline_access")
    
        .audience("\(audience)/userinfo")
        .start {
            switch $0 {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("token update failed")
                break
                // Handle error
            case .success(let credentials):
                // Pass the credentials over to the Credentials Manager
                credentialsManager.store(credentials: credentials)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(credentials.idToken, forKey: "id_token")
                print("token updated")
                
            }
    }
}
```

}

it is printing `not renewing` in my console. I'm not sure what I am missing here.

the login function works perfectly fine

```
func login() {
    Auth0
        .webAuth()
        .start { result in
            // Handle the result of the authentication
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                // If the authentication fails, print the error message
                print("Failed with: \(error)")
                
            case .success(let credentials):
                // If the authentication is successful, store the credentials and user information in UserDefaults
                self.userProfile = Profile.from(credentials.idToken)
                self.userIsAuthenticated = "1"
                print("Credentials: \(credentials)")
                
                // Store the ID token
                print("ID token: \(credentials.idToken)")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(credentials.idToken, forKey: "id_token")
                
                // Print and store the token type and access token
                print("token type: \(credentials.tokenType)")
                print("access token \(credentials.accessToken)")
                
                // Extract and store the user ID, name, and email from the user profile
                print("userID is \(userProfile.id)")
                let fullString = userProfile.id
                let parts = fullString.split(separator: "|")
                let desiredPart = String(parts[1])
                print(desiredPart)

                UserDefaults.standard.set(desiredPart, forKey: "userId")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(userProfile.name, forKey: "userName")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(userProfile.email, forKey: "userEmail")
                
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `canRenew()` is unable to find any stored credentials - Try using `credentialsManager.store` on initial login similar to how you are in `updateToken()`. This way the credentials are [stored in the keychain](https://github.com/auth0/Auth0.swift/blob/765e6e8cefbda600e34985ce14d7567f4d428e48/EXAMPLES.md#store-credentials) when a user logs in to begin with.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not renewing is because you didn't persist credentials in  CredentialsManager. More less something like this

```
self.credentialsManager.store(credentials: withCredentials)
```

Please check my code and adapt it to your needs

```
protocol AuthServiceProtocol {
  func login(email: String, password: String) async throws -> Credentials
  func refreshToken(withRefreshToken: String) async throws -> Credentials
  func register(email: String, password: String) async throws -> DatabaseUser
  func resetPassword(email: String) async throws
  func changePassword(email: String, password: String) async throws
  func requestEmailVerificationCode(email: String) async throws
  func verifyEmailVerificationCode(email: String, code: String) async throws
}
```

AuthService:

```
final class AuthService: ObservableObject {
  @Published var profile: ProfileModel?
  
  enum AuthError: LocalizedError {
    case expiredAuth
    case missingRefreshToken
    case notAuthenticated
    
    var errorDescription: String? {
      switch self {
      case .expiredAuth: return "Auth expired"
      case .notAuthenticated: return "User not authenticated"
      case .missingRefreshToken: return "Missing refresh token"
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  private let credentialsManager = CredentialsManager(authentication: Auth0.authentication())
  private let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  
  
  let authService: AuthServiceProtocol
  
  init(authService: AuthServiceProtocol) {
    self.authService = authService
  }
  
  func refreshToken() async throws {
    do {
      let refreshToken = try await getRefreshToken()
      let credentials = try await authService.refreshToken(withRefreshToken: refreshToken)
      
      loginWithAuthCredentials(credentials)
      
    } catch let error {
      throw error
    }
  }
  
  func getRefreshToken() async throws -> String {
    // check if user is persisted in the app loca credentials manager
    guard self.credentialsManager.canRenew() else {
      throw AuthError.notAuthenticated
    }
    
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
      credentialsManager.credentials { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let credentials):
          
          guard let refreshToken = credentials.refreshToken else {
            continuation.resume(throwing: AuthError.missingRefreshToken)
            return
          }
          
          continuation.resume(returning: refreshToken)
        case .failure(let error):
          continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  func getAuthenticatedUser() async throws -> ProfileModel {
    
    // check if user is persisted in the app loca credentials manager
    guard self.credentialsManager.canRenew() else {
      throw AuthError.notAuthenticated
    }
    
    return try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
      credentialsManager.credentials { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let credentials):
          
          
          // throw authExpired and refresh token if credentials expires in 5h from now
          if credentials.expiresIn < Date().addingTimeInterval(3600 * 5) {
            continuation.resume(throwing: AuthError.expiredAuth)
            return
          }
          
          continuation.resume(returning: ProfileModel.from(credentials.idToken))
        case .failure(let error):
          continuation.resume(throwing: error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  func loginWithAuthCredentials(_ withCredentials: Auth0.Credentials) {
    let _ = self.credentialsManager.store(credentials: withCredentials)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
      defaults.setValue(withCredentials.idToken, forKey: "authToken")
      profile = ProfileModel.from(withCredentials.idToken)
        
    }
  }

  func logout() {
    let _ = self.credentialsManager.clear()
    defaults.removeObject(forKey: "authToken")
  }
  
}
```

and in the app, on the very first View you can attach something like this:

```
struct RootView: View {
  
  //  @StateObject var authentication = Authentication()
  
  @StateObject private var authState: AuthService = AuthService(authService: Auth0Service())
  @State private var showSignInView: Bool = false
  let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
  
  var body: some View {
    
    VStack {
      if !showSignInView && authState.profile != nil {
        MainView(
          authState: authState,
          showSignInView: $showSignInView
        )
          .environment(
            \.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext
          )
      }
    }
    .onAppear {
      Task {
        do {
          let authUser = try await authState.getAuthenticatedUser()
          authState.profile = authUser
          self.showSignInView = false
          
        } catch AuthService.AuthError.expiredAuth {
          
          do {
            try await authState.refreshToken()
          } catch {
            authState.logout()
            self.showSignInView = true
            authState.profile = .empty
          }
          
        } catch {
          authState.logout()
          self.showSignInView = true
          authState.profile = .empty
        }
      }
    }
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSignInView, content: {
      WelcomView(
        authState: authState,
        showSignInView: $showSignInView
      )
    })
  }
}
```

Also keep in mind that in order to make it works you need to enable "Refresh Token Rotation" in your Auth0 App

[image]